# Python: Converting PIL.Image to a object that has object.read()

Tags: python-2.7

I have a variable of type PIL.Image.
I need to pass it to a function(that I didn't write) that will save it to disk for me. Let's call that function file_creator(my_PIL_image)

In the implementation of file_creator() a .read() method is used on my_PIL_image variable.

I need to convert my_PIL_image into a type that the file_creator() can read.

Any fancy suggestions?

Comment: You can save — to a [StringIO object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) — using PIL [Image.save](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.save). Remember to seek to the start of the StringIO pseudo-file before before passing it to the real file writer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution from a Python guy.
What I needed to do was encode the image to base64:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from base64 import b64encode

img_io = StringIO()
my_PIL_image.save(img_io, 'JPEG')
img_data = img_io.getvalue()
data_url = "data:image/jpg;base64," + b64encode(img_data)
```